# How to format source code in phpDesigner 7.x

Tags: phpdesigner

I am using phpDesigner and dont know how to format the source code in this IDE. Similar to right click and choose format in Netbeans (or Ctrl + Shift + F)
Does anyone know?

Thanks

---

Ok, I did it
For people who gets same problem: there are 2 ways 
1. Press combination: Ctrl + Shift + F1 
2. On the menu bar, select 'PHP' menu. Then select 'Code Beutifier for PHP' (the bottom option). Do the same with CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

there is beautifier for JavaScript too, it is online http://jsbeautifier.org/

in PhpDesigner no such option.

[javascript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)