# HTML code formatting in phpDesigner IDE version 7.0

Tags: php, html, phpdesigner

I am not being able to format the HTML tags using [phpdesigner](/questions/tagged/phpdesigner) IDE. PHP code beautifier in this IDE only formats the PHP code, not HTML tags.

Is there anyone, who is using PHP designer 7, to help me in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP Desinger 7:

1. CTRL + SHIFT + F1 or
2. 'PHP' menu > 'Code Beutifier for PHP'

Note: this helps in formatting PHP code, won't help for HTML or css or SCRIPT in well-format

In PHP Desinger 8 :

PHP Desinger 8 has the features for them as well. 
Visit [**this link**](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner_features.php#.UdaFMKwwHfY) for more detail of PHP designer 8.

Answer (score 2):

phpDesigner version 8.1.2

1. tools -> HTML CSS Javascript Formatter

[image]

2. then select Format HTML

[image]

3. click ok

Answer (score 0):

A little search around here would have helped you find out that someone else has asked the exact same question and solved it himself - posting the solution for others to enjoy.

Quoting "[How to format source code in phpDesigner 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790385/how-to-format-source-code-in-phpdesigner-7-x)"

> For people who gets same problem: there are 2 ways
>
> 1. Press combination: Ctrl + Shift + F1
> 2. On the menu bar, select 'PHP' menu. Then select 'Code Beutifier for PHP' (the bottom option). Do the same with CSS and HTML

Comment: I have gone through this question too. For PHP this process works but for CSS or HTML there is no option in php designer 7.